# "Move this discussion to chat" is effectively self-selecting

Tags: bug

Many times I will press `show more comments` and then go to press `add a comment`, and as I do the *Would you like to `automatically move this discussion to chat?`* question pops up.  This message pushes down the `add a comment` button and places itself (and its button) in the place of the "add a comment" button, causing you to press "move this discussion to chat" even though you had no intention of doing that.

It seems to me a simple fix to this problem would be to somehow rearrange/rephrase the full *Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to `automatically move this discussion to chat?`* message so that the "hot spot" does not land in the same real-estate that was previously occupied by `add a comment`.

Comment: I never noticed the positioning you're describing. That said, you make it sound positively lovely. Do you have any suggestions for how we could make this outcome *more* likely?

Comment: @Shog9 - You think it's a good idea to cause users to do things they had not intended to do??

Comment: The user might not intend to do it but it's the design goal as far as SE are concerned. Lengthy chats in comments aren't ideal and the chat system works far better in the cases where all relevant users have the necessary rep (which is another point altogether).

Comment: @Shog9: Almost every time I've had a discussion "continued in chat", I've seen only one party actually continue the discussion in chat.  So it effectively ends the discussion without a resolution.  Perhaps making the transition from "huge string of comments" to "ghetto IRC session" a little more seamless is the way to go if that's your goal?

Comment: Yeah, I've seen the same issue - if you've any suggestions for improving that, please post 'em.

Comment: I agree the positioning makes it less "an option" and also think the phrasing makes it somewhat self-selecting for new people. Today it took several comments to confirm that my answer would work for all users, and I saw the "Would you like to automatically move" question for the first time.  Almost clicked it thinking I could tell it "no, I wouldn't like that. (Please go away.)" Managed to avoid it and get to meta to find out how it worked.

Comment: @Shog9 I don't know whatever you saw my suggestion; just to make sure I replied so you will see it.

Answer (score 4):

As @Shog9 asked for idea; I think you may add warning message\dialog before actually opening a chat; something similar happened to me too. (With Jon Skeet ם.ם it was really embarrassing.)

I am surprised that it wasn't implemented before; from my impression overall, SO has really high design quality.

Comment: In the time it took Jon Skeet to join your chat room he made more reputation that you have.